# Verification of moderator behavior

Tags: support, moderators

I feel that moderator Carey Gregory ♦ deleted my answer for no reason.
Answer: https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/a/20570/17223

I tried to answer the best I know.

Please, can this moderator behavior be verified?
I have a bad feeling about censorship and hindering free research in this group, which should not be in conjunction with StackOverflow.com

Comment: https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers - I agree with the flag and the subsequent deletion.

Comment: @JohnP And what point of the rules did I break?
I gave a clear answer to the question asked.

Comment: No, actually you didn't. You gave a peripheral personal experience that doesn't meet the standards established for this site.

Comment: @JohnP Yes, that was my answer to the question. Which rule does this contradict? Please quote the rule and state the source on the rule.

Comment: @Ogi22 Bryan Krause answered that for you. Read his answer, including the links he provided.

Comment: @Carey Gregory 
01. I request a precise quote.
Because you obviously refer me to nothing that makes no sense in this respect.
If such a rule exists, there should be no problem citing it here.

02. Please follow the rules and provide the answer to the question and do not refer to someone else's answer....

Comment: @Ogi22 - We have provided you the reasons, and everything you wish to find is in the [help section](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/help). You have multiple moderators and high rep users telling you why, you simply don't want to accept that. You have also not even read the basic introduction page on any site you are a member of.

Comment: @JohnP I request a precise quote. Because you obviously refer me to nothing that makes no sense in this respect. If such a rule exists, there should be no problem citing it here. 02. Please follow the rules and provide the answer to the question and do not refer to someone else's answer....I know this is a repetitive comment, but you haven't answered my question. Please answer my question so we can continue.

Answer (score 4):

I flagged your answer as low-quality, which is probably what drew moderator attention to it though they likely would have made the decision themselves.

Your answer was not an answer according to the standards of this site. See some relevant meta posts:

[Should we require references to back up all answers?](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/should-we-require-references-to-back-up-all-answers)

[Should answers without references be immediately deleted?](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/283/should-answers-without-references-be-immediately-deleted)

Your answer was not referenced and based on anecdote and pseudoscience. It was poorly formatted and makes many claims not held to be true by medical science. This is not a site for you to opine about the motives of shampoo manufacturers, it is a site about medical science for professionals, students, and others interested in health-related sciences.

Answer (score 3):

Your post was deleted because it didn't answer the question and it lacked supporting references. Please read the [help center](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/help) and take [the tour](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/tour) to learn how the site works and what's expected of questions and answers.

Comment: 01. And what should I do if there is no reference but I draw on my long-standing knowledge throughout my life?
Should I spend 4 days looking for references that include the lines of experience I wrote there?
Should I create a new website, or a new scientific research specifically focused on the subject?
Please let the community add, express or disagree.
You as an individual are not a community.

02. How can I answer a question that makes no sense?
How should I answer the question, "Why didn't my second head grow up to this day?"

Comment: @Ogi22 Read Bryan Krause's answer.

Comment: Please answer my question, it is dedicated to your answer.
Don't link me to someone else while I respond to your post.
For his answer, I have the same question as yours.

Comment: @Ogi22 We've answered your questions repeatedly. It's obvious you're ignoring what we write and just want to have your way. Well, as soon as you convince a majority of the community here to see it your way, you can have your way. Until then, the rules established by that community will be enforced.

Comment: As I understand from posts and links, you have completely misunderstood how stackexchange.com works.
Preference is given to entire responses even without a link, and not just those with a link.
Comments are for help with clarification.
The site acts as a public knowledge base of quality questions and quality answers.
You make it the questions you allow and the answers you allow.

Comment: Please read this:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer
https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7656/how-do-i-write-a-good-answer-to-a-question

Comment: @Ogi22 You're right that one of us doesn't know how stackexchange works. **Your post didn't answer the question that was asked.** That will get an answer closed on every site on the exchange. But I'm glad you posted the link above. Now please go read it and pay particular attention to the section labeled **Answer the question**.

Comment: Also note that discussions on the main meta do not always apply in the exact same way to all Stack Exchange sites. The scientific stacks have requirements that differ from the others, and Medical Sciences in particular is more heavily moderated due to the higher potential personal harm of poor answers due to the subject matter. One of the key features for how StackExchange works is the self-governance of the individual stacks. See for example https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/322333/who-decides-on-a-sites-content-policy

Comment: The things you tell do not make sense.
They are absolutely at odds with education.
If one decides to operate the brain because he has seen a description of the operation on the Internet, it is his problem and his responsibility.
You are not telling anyone to do this or that the information you write will work in his case as well.
You artificially block progress in this matter.
Stackexchange is extraordinary in how it works, but you have garbled it so that it absolutely fails its purpose.
You simply don't want people without sacrificing life for years of study to come to a solution.

Comment: @Ogi22 Your expertise on stackexchange is curious given that you have no positive rep on any site except Photography, where you have 9 points. The very little activity you've engaged in network-wide has almost universally been downvoted, closed, or deleted. So it seems you have a problem reading and following site guidelines. But here you are lecturing us on what's wrong with this site and telling us how we should overhaul it to fit your opinions. Given that you've never participated in any of the meta discussions that established this site's policies, that takes a lot of gall.

Comment: 01. It seems that I am not the only one who has a problem with moderators behavior on this Medical Sciences at stackexchange.com
https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/q/747/17223
https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1068/17223

02. Nowhere else have my posts been deleted, just only here at Medical Sciences at stackexchange.com a few minutes before I published them.

03. I don't have a few other friends on this site with whom we push each other with each other, so we're not making false points.

...

Comment: ...04. I live in the real world and not here.

05. My beginner mistakes were beginner mistakes that I fixed and learned how to write.
Just because I learned it, I know you are doing something wrong on this site.

Comment: @Ogi22 - Please read some of the meta questions regarding backing up of answers. We are much like skeptics and a few other SE sites, in that we require medical citations and credible published research to validate answers. Simply stating a personal experience does not meet the standards set for this site.

Comment: @JohnP "standards set for this site" Which do you think?